# Azure Nested Virtualization Networking

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

I created a Server 2019 VM in Azure and want to use nested virtualization. On the 2019 VM, I created a Windows 10 VM in Hyper-V. The problem is that the Windows 10 VM does not have internet connection. Even though a virtual switch was created on the 2019 VM, the nested Windows 10 VM is not able to reach the Azure gateway.

Here's the Server 2019 Network settings

[image: Server 2019 Network settings]

This is the Hyper-V Switch

[image: hyper-v switch settings]

And finally this is the Windows 10 VM network settings. It never gets an IP address from the host and even when assigned a static IP it cannot route to the gateway. What am I missing?

[image]

The overall problem I'm trying to solve is to have Apache Guacamole able to connect to nested VMs, which isn't possible with NATing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reach the internet because your default gateway is blank.

You are getting auto configured IP addresses without default gateway (169....) (probably) because you do not have a DHCP server.

> You can configure the DHCP server on the Hyper-V host running in Azure
> or on a nested Hyper-V VM if needed.

see: https://www.nakivo.com/blog/hyper-v-nested-virtualization-on-azure-complete-guide/